# Problems with java FilePermission class

Tags: java

I have to make some code for java classes about files permission, and I found `FilePermission` class. But when I tried to use it to change my files permissions, nothing happened. I know i can use `file.setReadable` or something. But my question is whether I can change permissions using `FilePermission` class and if not what this class is meant for

```
String pathToFolder="C:\\tmp\\file.txt";

FilePermission folderPermission = new FilePermission("C:\\tmp\\*", "read");

PermissionCollection permission = folderPermission.newPermissionCollection();

permission.add(folderPermission);

FilePermission dataPermission = new FilePermission(pathToFolder, "write");

permission.add(dataPermission);

if(permission.implies(new FilePermission(pathToFolder, "read, write"))) {
    System.out.println("Read, Write permission is granted for the path "+pathToFolder);
}
else {
    System.out.println("No Read, Write permission is granted for the path " + pathToFolder);
}
```

Now I can use it to compare two permissions on `PermissioCollection`, but it still doesnt change permissions on real files.

Thanks for all your help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Java documentation for [FilePermission](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html), clearly states that, this java class is used to represent the actions (i.e read/write/delete/execute/readlink). It does NOT change the permission of existing file/folder.

You can tough perform an "implies" action as you have defined in your example.

FilePermission class helps to resolve crucial file access decisions (using implies method) which if implemented manually can lead to errors or security breaches like any other permission class.